# postgres - total grouped rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following sql:

```
SELECT
    count(status),
    status
FROM stats  
GROUP BY status
```

and getting following result:

```
+-----------+----------+
| status    | COUNT(*) |
+-----------+----------+
| SUCCESS   |        2 | 
| ERROR     |        5 | 
+-----------+----------+
```

However I want to get additionally total rows (total=SUCCESS+ERROR):

```
+-----------+----------+
| status    | COUNT(*) |
+-----------+----------+
| SUCCESS   |        2 | 
| ERROR     |        5 | 
| total     |        7 | 
+-----------+----------+
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it with `ROLLUP` subclause:

```
SELECT
    count(status),
    coalesce(status, 'total')
FROM stats  
GROUP BY 
    ROLLUP(status)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GROUPING SETS` for that:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=cec06bbf91a9aff2e7e08dcb4335edc4)

```
SELECT
    count(status),
    status
FROM stats  
GROUP BY 
GROUPING SETS ((status), ())
```

This returns a `NULL` value instead of `total`. This can be fixed using `COALESCE()`

```
SELECT
    count(status),
    COALESCE(status, 'total')
FROM stats  
GROUP BY 
GROUPING SETS ((status), ()) 
ORDER BY count
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It brings me to read more about groupings and I found `ROLLUP`